# Как из документов с кодом получается сайт в интернете?

Tags: веб-программирование

Я изучаю web-программирование. Уже знаю основы html, css, сейчас изучаю JavaScript. Я пишу код в блокноте и у меня уже есть документы с кодом html и css. Но для меня не понятен процесс создания сайта. Нашел в интернете, что необходимо выбрать доменное имя, оплатить хостинг, после чего загружать файлы на сервер.

Итак, вопрос: собственно как из документов с кодом получается сайт в интернете?

Comment: Настраивается Web-сервер, на него заливаются файлы с кодом. Дополнительно - прикручивается доменное имя.

Comment: Можете без аренды хостинга попробовать например на github.io

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно решить две задачи: хостинг и домен.

1. **Хостинг.** Сайт должен лежать на каком-то компьютере с выходом в интернет. Желательно, чтобы компьютер был включен всегда. Быстрый вариант "для чайника" - [положить все файлы в Гугл Драйв и расшарить их как сайт](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=ru). Менее быстрый вариант - найти хостинг. Бесплатных хостингов существуют сотни, если не тысячи, у меня [первым в выдаче выпал Hostinger](http://www.hostinger.ru/besplatnui-hosting), а вообще на слуху `narod.ru`, `ucoz.ru`.

   Теперь ваш сайт лежит в интернете по некоему неудобоваримому адресу, типа `123.123.123.123/userololo/www/index.html`, а то и похуже. Давайте регистрировать клевый домен!
2. **Домен.**
   Домен первого уровня (`TLD`, `top level domain`) - это `.ru`, `.com`, `.io`, `.xyz` и прочие. Такой нам регистрировать пока не по зубам.

   Домен второго уровня (`superdomenololo.com` или `superdomenololo.ru`) стоит $5-10 долларов в год. Купить его нам поможет Регистратор. Популярные регистраторы - `godaddy.com`, `nic.ru`, `reg.ru`, тысячи их. После покупки, следуйте инструкциям регистратора и хостера. Вам помогут отредактировать технические записи, чтобы адрес `tvojdomen.ru` указывал на компьютер с айпи `123.123.123.123` (например).

   Домен третьего уровня часто бесплатно выдают хостеры. То есть если ваш хостер некий `hosterololo.ru`, то он может вам даром позволить "сесть на хвост" своему домену и разместить ваш сайт по адресу `mojnovijsajt.hosterololo.ru`. Что тоже неплохо запоминается.

Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

На компьютере, который работает сервером, должна быть установлена специальная программа. Она тоже называется сервером. Основной алгоритм работы любой программы сервера - ждать запросов от клиентов и на каждый полученный запрос отправлять ответ. Какой вид имеют запрос и ответ, определяется типом сервера. Для веб-сайтов применяются веб-сервера. Они общаются с клиентами (в вебе клиент - это, как правило, браузер) по протоколу HTTP или HTTPS (протокол - это как раз описание формата запросов и ответов). Получив запрос, программа-сервер определяет соответствие URL (Интернет-адрес, который пользователь набирает в адресной строке браузера) и пути к файлу на диске ПК. Затем она либо отправляет клиенту файл с диска (чаще всего это html-документ), либо сообщает об ошибке (если файла на диске нет, или запрос был неправильный). Страницы статических сайтов (html-документы) лежат в специальной папке на диске ПК-сервера, откуда их и берёт программа-сервер. Что это за папка, зависит от программы сервера и её настроек. Ещё бывают динамические сайты, когда файл генерируется сервером "на лету", когда поступает запрос клиента. Но это уже отдельная тема.

---

Хостинг предоставляет ресурсы постоянно работающего ПК, на котором установлены все нужные программы. Этого достаточно, чтобы сайт был доступен всем в Интернете по ip-адресу компьютера-сервера. Но люди обычно не запоминают ip-адрес сайтов + он может меняться по техническим причинам. Поэтому обычно покупают ещё доменное имя. За соответствие ip-адресов и доменных имён отвечает служба DNS. Когда пользователь вводит в адресной строке браузера адрес сайта, содержащий доменное имя, браузер отправляет запрос к DNS-серверу. DNS-сервер возвращает в ответе ip-адрес, соответствующий доменному имени.

---

Вообще-то, если установить программу-сервер (например, Apache или NGinx) на Ваш собственный ПК, то он тоже сможет хостить сайт. Но так сейчас обычно не делают по нескольким причинам:

1. Во-первых, сайт будет доступен только, пока Ваш ПК включен.
2. Во-вторых, провайдеры обычно предоставляют клиентам динамические ip-адреса. То есть при каждом подключении к Интернету у Вас будет разный ip-адрес. В принципе, есть способы, позволяющие привязать динамический ip-адрес к доменному имени, но это всё долго, сложно и не очень надёжно. Можно получить у провайдера статический ip (он не меняется между подключениями). Но это стоит денег.
3. Расходы на электричество, статический ip-адрес и более быстрый расход ресурса ПК из-за постоянной работы вполне сопоставимы с расходами на хостинг.

Впрочем, если речь идёт о поиграться, а не о серьёзном проекте, то можно использовать и бесплатный хостинг, и домашний ПК в качестве сервера. Просто надо помнить об ограничениях.